# Accessing EJS variable on script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm building a node.js app and I want to access an array from the server, I found out that I can't access the array on the script tag.

I searched for solutions and found a solution to `JSON.stringify` but it doesn't work and returns an error.

*The server side with express:*

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    const coffepoints = await CoffePoint.find({});
    res.render('coffepoints/index', { coffepoints })
}
```

*Client side:*

```
<script> 
    const coffepoints = <% - JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>
</script>
```

What should I do to access the array in the script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is actually called `includes`, which is for partials in EJS.

```js
<script> const coffepoints = <% - JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %></script>
                               ^^^
```

You want to display, or output an EJS variable. So, you would use `<%=` tag.

```js
<script> const coffepoints = <%= JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %></script>
```

You can view the EJS documentation [here](https://ejs.co/#docs), which includes all the available tags in EJS.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply access it with `<%= varName %>` from express

```js
<script>
    var myVal = <%= someVal %>
</script>
```

Comment: That only works if `someVal` is a number or boolean. That doesn't seem to be the case here.